# Best notation for partial derivatives

Tags: notation, soft-question, partial-derivative

I know this one is a soft question so I will tag it as such, but I'm aware of the following ways in which derivatives are represented:

lets say we have a function:
$$f=f(x,y)$$
then the derivative wrt $x$ e.g. is:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
but often it will be written as:
$$\partial_xf,\,f_x$$
and several other forms. The reason I ask is because I find when you have equations with large amounts of derivates it can be tedious to type or write them all out fully, e.g.:
$$\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial r^2}+\frac1r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial\theta^2}=0$$
can be nicely abbreviated to:
$$\partial^2_rT+\frac{\partial_rT}{r}+\frac{\partial^2_\theta T}{r^2}=0$$
or maybe:
$$T_{rr}+\frac1rT_r+\frac1{r^2}T_{\theta\theta}=0$$
Does anyone have any opinions on which shorthand is the least ambiguous or is more generally accepted, or if you have any other interesting notation I'd like to see. I am also aware of common notation like: $\Delta,\nabla$

Comment: I think with time you will find that different notations are convenient for different purposes. I don't think there is a "best one" out there.
Also, the words "I don't think" in this comment kind of give you a hint that this question is primarly opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no analyst, but at least when you're dealing with functions with a lot of indices (for instance the coefficients of a metric on a manifold in local coordinates are written $g_{ij}$), the last notation using e.g.
$$
\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}=(g_{ij})_k
$$
or something will quickly become a headache. I think a good balance of efficiency and clarity is using notation like
$$
\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}=\partial_kg_{ij}
$$
for instance. Or
$$
\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t}=\partial_tg_{ij}.
$$